# Get only updated rows using Live Data

Tags: java, android, android-livedata

I am using Room for db operations. 
In one scenario where I am using TreeView (custom lib) to inflate data. 
Inflated data change over time.
Is there any why that my LiveData Observer only return those records which has updated? So I dont need to inflate whole TreeView.

Comment: no, there is no such way

Comment: @pskink any workaround?

Comment: workaround for what? what do you mean by `"I dont need to inflate whole TreeView."`?

Comment: Like how we use diffutil to calculate and update the view in recyclerview.

Comment: I dont need to inflate whole TreeView. : 

If i get only updated row then i can able to update only treenode which is correspondent to that row data

Comment: so use `RecyclerView` with [ListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter) or [PagedListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedListAdapter?hl=en) or ask the authors of your `TreeView` (whatever it is) how to do that

Comment: Noted, Thanks for quick response.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> No, There is no such way

as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55843791/get-only-updated-rows-using-live-data#comment98349979_55843791) comment